# Simple hangman game from beginner

Tags: python, beginner, hangman

This is the first project I am attempting in **Python**, and my first time on Stack Exchange, so please be kind.

The game uses a text file with lots of words. I was wondering how to improve the game by having different difficulty levels. E.g. easy for 1-4 letters, medium for 5-8 letters, hard for 9+ letters in the word.
All the code in `print_graphics()` was pre-made, so I have to figure out a way to incorporate it into the code I was writing.

I was also thinking it might look neater if it didn't keep printing new iterations of the hangman after each body part is added, but I'm not sure how I could do that without massively changing the text.

I couldn't figure out how to attach the input file (user interaction) so I've linked it instead.

```
import random
from IPython.display import clear_output
from termcolor import colored

def print_graphics(wrong_guesses):
    # list of possible body parts
    body_parts = ['  O     |', '  |     |',' /|     |', ' /|\    |', ' /      |', ' / \    |']
    
    # how many lines to print
    lines = 4 if wrong_guesses != 0 else 5

    # check number provided is usable
    if 0 <= wrong_guesses <= 6:
        print('  +-----+')  # print top of frame
        print('  |     |')
    
        # print the correct body parts for current state
        if wrong_guesses > 0:
            if wrong_guesses > 1:
                print(body_parts[0])
                lines -= 1
            if wrong_guesses > 4:
                print(body_parts[3])
                lines -= 1
            print(body_parts[wrong_guesses-1])

        for i in range(lines):
            print('        |')  # print the lines
        
        print('==========')  # print the floor


with open("wordlist.txt") as file:
  words = file.read().split()
  word = random.choice(words)

guessed_word = []
guessed_letters = []
max_guesses = 5
length_word = len(word)
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
letter_storage = []
body_parts = ['  O     |', '  |     |',' /|     |', ' /|\    |', ' /      |', ' / \    |']


def start():
  print("\033[1;34m"+"Welcome to hangman! You have 6 tries to guess the correct word, enter a letter to get started", "\033[0;30m")
start()

def intro():
  for character in word:
    guessed_word.append("_")
  print("The word you are guessing has", length_word, "characters")
  print_graphics(0)
intro()

def play(word):
  wrong_guesses = 0
  while wrong_guesses <6:
    guess = input("Guess a letter or word: ")

    if guess in guessed_letters:
      print("\033[1;31m"+"Whoops! You have already guessed this letter. Don't worry, you still have", 6-wrong_guesses, "guesses remaining" "\033[0;30m")
    if guess not in alphabet:
      print("\033[1;31m"+"Character invalid. Please enter a letter", "\033[0;30m")
    
    elif guess in alphabet and guess not in guessed_letters:
      if guess in word: 
        print("\033[1;3;32m"+"Well done", guess.upper(), "is correct!", "\033[0;30m")
        guessed_letters.append(guess)
        for i in range(0, length_word):
          if word[i] == guess:
            guessed_word[i] = guess
        print(guessed_word)
        if not "_" in guessed_word:
          print("\033[1;3;32m"+"Congratulations, you beat the Hangman!", "\033[0;30m")
          break 

      elif guess not in word:
        wrong_guesses += 1
        print(print_graphics(wrong_guesses))
        print(guessed_word)
        print("\033[1;31m"+guess.upper(), "is not correct. You have", 6-wrong_guesses, "guesses left", "\033[0;30m")
        guessed_letters.append(guess)    
    if wrong_guesses == 6:
      print("\033[1;31m"+"Bad luck! You have been beaten by the Hangman. The word you were trying to guess was", word, "\033[0;30m")
  



play(word)
print("\033[1;3;35m"+"Game over, thank you for playing :)")
```

Comment: On Code Review, we can offer advice on improving the existing code.  Changes to the functionality (adding difficulty levels) are off-topic, so don't expect reviewers to add that for you!

Comment: I wasn't looking for anyone to do the code for me as I am trying to learn! I was simply hoping someone could review the code and suggest how to read the number of characters in the words in the file. so far I have: `def difficulty(word):
  print("Easy = word has 2-4 characters\nMedium = word has 5-8 characters\nHard = word has 9+ characters")
  diff = input("Do you want easy, medium or hard?")

  if diff is easy:
    len(word) >= 2 and <= 4
  if diff is medium:
    len(word) >= 5 and <= 8
  if diff is hard: 
    len(word) >9
difficulty(word)` but there is nothing about the file

Comment: Code review is not a site to ask for new features, we only review existing features and provide insight on how it might be improved.

Answer (score 2):

You write

> ```
> from termcolor import colored
> ```

but then ignore that and write non-portable escape sequences directly in the strings:

> ```
>   print("\033[1;34m"+"....", "\033[0;30m")
> ```

Doesn't that defeat the point of `termcolor`, which is supposed to adapt to the connected terminal?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I tried to it that way originally but it wasn't working and I forgot to remove that module